# Aggregate data from multiple records

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am attempting to create a report using PostgreSQL that lists a doctor, number of ratings for a particular question, and the average of those ratings as one record.

I've made the following simple query:

```
select p.token, count(r.id), avg(a.val)
from xx.tb1 r
inner join xx.tb2 p using (id)
inner join xx.tb3 a using (id)
where a.question_id = 1
group by token
```

What would be the most efficient method to add the consecutive question_id's to the query? I can use the same simple query in multiple select statements, but that does not seem the most efficient method. A union will not work because I want the data grouped by doctor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply add the question_id as a column. Then you will have as many rows for each doctor as you have questions.

```
select p.token, a.question_id, count(r.review_id), avg(a.val_num_raw)
from xx.review r
inner join xx.predicate p using (predicate_id)
inner join xx.answer a using (review_id)
group by token, a.question_id
```

**Edit**
Based on your comment below, you should either A) Pivot your data in a tool like Excel (or use MS SQL 2012 which can pivot as a feature) or B) Build a horrible query like the one below:

```
select q1.token, q1.cnt, q1.av, q2.cnt, q2.av, ...
FROM (
    select p.token, count(r.review_id) as cnt, avg(a.val_num_raw) as av
    from xx.review r
    inner join xx.predicate p using (predicate_id)
    inner join xx.answer a using (review_id)
    where question_id = 1
    group by token) q1
LEFT JOIN (
    select p.token, count(r.review_id) as cnt, avg(a.val_num_raw) as av
    from xx.review r
    inner join xx.predicate p using (predicate_id)
    inner join xx.answer a using (review_id)
    where question_id = 2
    group by token) q2 using (token)
LEFT JOIN (
    select p.token, count(r.review_id) as cnt, avg(a.val_num_raw) as av
    from xx.review r
    inner join xx.predicate p using (predicate_id)
    inner join xx.answer a using (review_id)
    where question_id = 3
    group by token) q3 using (token)
```

I would pivot because the performance of this query is going to be horrible.

Comment: doctor|count(question_id_1)|avg(question_id_1)|count(question_id_2)|avg(question_id_2)

Comment: The above would be one record of the report.

Comment: What you are looking to do based on your comment above is pivot the data.   There are techniques for doing this in SQL, but personally if I need to pivot data I move the data into a reporting tool that is strong at pivoting.   Excel is a good one.   If you can do that then I think @DigitialD has answered your question.

Comment: I was just having a scan through [this](http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/06/27/Pivoting-in-Postgres/) article about pitvoting in Postgres. @swhit, if this must be done in PostgreSQL, maybe this will help.

Comment: I'm trying to return one row per doctor.

Comment: @DigitalD Thank you. Just one question, using subqueries in the select statement would be equally horrible, correct?

Comment: Subqueries in the select statement would be more horrible. I'm not sure if the query optimizer could combine aggregate functions like you can ahead of time with my example. Though again, a pivot would produce even better performance.